# Change color of Icon-Image on :hover – what other ways are there?

Tags: html, css, hover

I have the following problem and it drives me crazy:

Basicly I have a div-container with an background. This background should change when I hover it (see pichture). It is an png and instead of white it should turn red.

## What I have done until now:

### First: CSS sprite

Thought it will be the best solution but becuase the div changes it's size (responsive) and the icon does not have a fixed size it was not very clean: I had a small offset on hovering. Not sure why… mybe this can be fixed…

### Second: 2 separate images

But this is not an option in this case because I need to work with inline styles. :hover ist not available as inline style.

### Thrid: tried mask-box-image

Was a woderful solution… but Firefox does not support it.

Does anyone has another idea how to solve it?

[image]

Comment: Can you share the code you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

May be it will help

I posted an example following

```css
.box {
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  background:tomato;
}

.box:hover {
  background: transparent;
}

.box:hover span {
  color: tomato;
}

.box span {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span>a</span>
  <span>----</span>
  <span>b</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give This a Try

CSS

```
.icon-cont{
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  text-align:center;
}
.icon-cont:hover{
  background-color: transparent;
}
.icon-cont:hover .icon,
.icon-cont:hover .icon::before,
.icon-cont:hover .icon::after
{
  border-color:#ff0000;
}
.icon{
  height:0px;
  border-bottom:2px solid #fff;
  width:60%;
  line-height:300px;
  position: relative;
  margin:auto;
  top:50%;
}
.icon::before{
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  left:-30px;
  margin:auto;
  height:20px;
  width:20px;
  border:2px solid #fff;
  border-radius:50px;
}

.icon::after{
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  right:-30px;
  margin:auto;
  height:20px;
  width:20px;
  border:2px solid #fff;
  border-radius:50px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="icon-cont">
  <div class="icon"></div>
</div>
```

[Link for reference](https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/ek4q81je/1/)

hope this helps..

Comment: Nice. Thanks. But this is only one of many more images… some of them are more complex… 
But nice one!

Answer (score 0):

You can't change color of .png with css. I think you should make a font out of your icons in order to change their color with css later.

I haven't done that myself, but I know those fonts, like font-awesome can change color. There are some automatic generators in google to make your own font.

Try this.